# Is there a way to center text in a ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way in `ggplot2`, to either

1. Programmatically access the x and y axis range for the grid area or
2. Tell `geom_text` to center text in the middle of the plot area

Example

```
testData <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4), b=rnorm(100, 1, 3), c=rnorm(100))
ggplot(testData) + geom_point(aes(x=a, y = b)) + geom_text(aes(x=a, y = 0, label="label"))
```

I would like to avoid having to manually set the range of the y axis, since I am generating a large number of charts automatically and would prefer to have `ggplot2` determine the right range to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
g1 <- ggplot(testData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = a, y = mean(range(b)), label="label"))

g1
```

[image]

And Q1, if you want to access the ranges for the plot area:

```
# build plot object for rendering
gg1 <- ggplot_build(g1)

gg1$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.range
gg1$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range

# mid-point of y-range from plot object 
mean(gg1$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range)
# [1] 0.5517525

# mid-point used in plot above
with(testData, y = mean(range(b)))
# [1] 0.5517525
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Henrik idea of use y mid value, but I would also set the y limits manually using `ylim` or `scale_y_continuous` :

```
y.ranges <- c(-100,100)
ggplot(testData,aes(x=a, y = b)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = y.ranges) +
  geom_text(aes(x=a, y =mean(range(y.ranges)) , label="label"))
```