# How to fix the geom_text label position so it is always on the middle of the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a function that produce a ggplot graph.

```
data1 <- data.table(x=1:5, y=1:5, z=c(1,2,1,2,1))
data2 <- data.table(x=1:5, y=11:15, z=c(1,2,1,2,1))

myfun <- function(data){
    ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_text(aes(label=y), y=3) +
        facet_grid(z~.)
}

myfun(data2)
```

It is supposed to label some text on the graph. However, without knowing the data in advance I am unable to adjust the positions of text vertically manually. Especially I don't want the label to move positions with data: I want it always stays at about 1/4 vertically of the plots. (top-mid)

How can I do that?

Is there a function that returns the `y.limit.up` and `y.limit.bottom` then I can assign `y = (y.limit.up + y.limit.bottm) / 2` or something.

Comment: [Here are some alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103646/is-there-a-way-to-center-text-in-a-ggplot2/19104031#19104031)

Comment: Something similar asked earlier [today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142505/how-to-put-a-text-label-on-a-plot-located-independently-from-the-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting either x or y position in `geom_text(...)` relative to the plot scale in a facet is actually a pretty big problem. @agstudy's solution works if the y scale is **the same for all facets**. This is because, in calculating range (or max, or min, etc), `ggplot` uses the unsubsetted data, not the data subsetted for the appropriate facet ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058902/)).

You can achieve what you want using auxiliary tables, though.

```
data1 <- data.table(x=1:5, y=1:5, z=c(1,2,1,2,1))
data2 <- data.table(x=1:5, y=11:15, z=c(1,2,1,2,1))

myfun <- function(data){
    label.pos <- data[,ypos:=min(y)+0.75*diff(range(y)),by=z] # 75% to the top...

    ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_point() +
    #   geom_text(aes(label=y), y=3) +
        geom_text(data=label.pos, aes(y=ypos, label=y)) +
        facet_grid(z~., scales="free")     # note scales = "free"
}

myfun(data2)
```

Produces this.

[image]

If you want scales="fixed", then @agstudy's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this for example:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=x)) +
        geom_point(aes(y=y)) +
        geom_text(aes(label=y, y=mean(range(y)))) +
        facet_grid(z~.)
```

Or fix y limits manually:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 15))
```

Comment: Seems to be useful only with simple plots. What about more complicated plots like `geom_density`? This won't work
(Same question for @jlhoward)

Answer (score 0):

@user890739 :
with geom_density you can estimate an ypos variable like this :

```
data<-dplyr::mutate(group_by(data, z), ypos=max(density(y)$y)*.75*nrow(data))
```

Then plot the result :

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) +
    stat_density(aes(y=..density..)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=y, y=ypos)) +
    facet_grid(z~., scales="free")
```